# Edit a yaml file without losing its initial structure using python

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

How can we edit a yaml file without losing its initial structure , for example

This is my initial structure of the yaml file

```
    ---
  Feature:
    version : 1.0.1
    artifactId : libraries
    groupId : com.fgr.fff.ddds
    extension : zip
    classifier : dfdd
    properties: {storage : ds, aem_group : vbox}
    type : packages
    order : 100
```

This is my output

```
Feature:
  artifactId: libraries
  classifier: dfdd
  extension: zip
  groupId: com.fgr.fff.ddds
  order: 100
  properties: {storage : ds, aem_group : vbox}
  type: packages
  version: 1.0.1
```

(As you can see the spaces are removed from the original structure of the file)

I'm using yaml.load() to load the file and yaml.dump() to update the file.
Is there any way to handle this ?

Comment: Which spaces? and try `re.sub()`

Comment: see the screenshots ...i updated them (just to get a clearer picture)

Comment: AFAIK there is no YAML parser that preserves this kind of inconsistently applied space (`groupId :`) or no space (`properties :`) information.  From such a small sample one can guess, but not be sure what the rule for adding the unnecessary space is. What program wrote this kind of file? Why does this matter? You are obviously not going to diff the file otherwise you would be more upset  about the chance of order of keys in the mapping.

Comment: You should not post screenshots, include the data as code. (indent the whole block with four spaces using `{}` button)

Comment: Actually this code will eventually be pick up (read) by another code to which the spaces will eventually matter, however the order in which the key value pairs  are coming will not matter.

Comment: If the spaces matter, that's either a bug in that code because YAML explicitly states that spacing must not convey content information, or you actually do not use YAML, but just something that resembles YAML, in which case using YAML implementations to edit it obviously leads to problems.

Comment: As @flyx indicated the code that picks that up might not be YAML based. Can you divulge what programs expect this? If they are open source, maybe one of us can find the time to help make that standards conform.